# SQL query help, data is now showing in 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a problem in composing a SQL query

```
Sculptor (SRID, SR_FName, SR_LName, SR_DOB) 
Sculpture (SEID, SE_Name, SE_Value, SRID*, SID*)
Model (MID, M_FName, M_LName, M_Salary)
```

List the sculptor last name and total sculpture value (as one field named “Total
Sculpture Value”) of all the sculptures that each sculptor has sculpted (rounded to two decimal places), sorted in ascending order by total value. Only list those sculptors whose total sculpture value is less than 100,000.

My query is:

```
SELECT SR_LName,
       SE_Value AS TotalSculptureValue
FROM   Sculptor
       JOIN Sculpture USING (SRID)
HAVING ( SE_Value ) < 100000
```

Comment: You need to use an aggregate:  `SUM(value)` ... `GROUP BY name`. I'm responding in a comment rather than giving you the complete answer because it's vitally important you learn to use aggregate functions.

Comment: means ? how  why i use SUM ?? can you plz explain little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to learn to use aggregate functions, but here's how this one would work:

```
SELECT SR_LName,
       sum(SE_Value) AS "TotalSculptureValue"
FROM   Sculptor
       JOIN Sculpture USING (SRID)
group by SR_LName
```

Try running that query first. You should see all of the sculptor names with the sum of their values.

Then add the `HAVING` back in, because that's how you restrict the results of aggregate functions:

```
SELECT SR_LName,
       sum(SE_Value) AS "TotalSculptureValue"
FROM   Sculptor
       JOIN Sculpture USING (SRID)
group by SR_LName
having sum(SE_Value) < 100000
```

`HAVING` is different from `WHERE`. If you want to restrict the non-aggregated columns, like name, you would use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT SR_LName,
       sum(SE_Value) AS "TotalSculptureValue"
FROM   Sculptor
       JOIN Sculpture USING (SRID)
where SR_LName like '%Ali%'
group by SR_LName
having sum(SE_Value) < 100000
```

This would give you all sculptors with names that contain Ali and have total value of less than 100000.